# How do I retrieve songs hidden in the iCloud with iTunes 11.0.4?

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, music, itunes-store

My younger sister bought a few pop songs on my mom's computer (which is not an Apple but she has iTunes on it), and because of the iCloud they showed up on my computer as well. I really can't stand her songs (I've always been a major classic rock fan), so I deleted them from my Mac not knowing that they would also delete them from my mom's computer. Then she and my mom got mad that her songs were deleted, so I looked up how to retrieve them. I went to the iTunes store > Account Information > iTunes in the Cloud, but the only thing there was "Manage Devices" and "iTunes Match." There's no option to view hidden songs in between those two options, like it's supposed to. I just updated iTunes so that I have iTunes 11.0.4, but it still doesn't show up. Is there anything else I can do? I really don't want to re-buy her songs.

Comment: You r in trouble :(

Comment: You can not retrieve the songs that she purchased using hers itunes account.

Comment: We both used her iTunes account, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: OK, then: Go to 'iTunes Store',' Account',
Under 'iTunes in the Cloud' (section) there should be something about hidden songs or purchases.
Go in there and select the purchases to  'un hide'.

Answer (score 2):

1) Open iTunes

2) Go to Store

3) Go to Music Tab

4) On the Right Hand Side should be a link "Purchased" - click that.

5) Then "Recent Purchases"

6) Click on the little cloud icon to redownload what you want.

However you should be able to delete from your computer without affecting music on other computers so I am confused by your description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up iTunes
2. Highlight "Music" in the Sidebar
3. Click on "View" in the Menu Bar (that will open a drop-down menu)
4. Go down the drop down menu and click on "Show Music in the Cloud"
5. Your songs/albums will now be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Look for it in iTunes Store and buy it again. Once you add your information it will tell you that you have already bought it and that you can download it from free (press download to download it again for free)